# Why use the pip in a conda virtual environment makes the global effect?

Tags: tensorflow, pip, anaconda, conda, tensorflow2.0

previously, I installed the tensorflow 1.13 in my machine.
There are some projects depending on different version of tensorflow and I do not want to mixed up different version of tensowflow.

So I just tried create a env called tf2.0 and used pip to install tensorflow 2.0.0b1 in that specific virtual environment.

However, after I ran 'pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0b1` in that "tf2.0" conda environment, I found that it takes effect globally, which mean I have to use tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0b1 even when that virtual env "tf2.0" disactivated.

I wish I could use tensorflow 1.13 when virtual env is deactivated.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the question- could you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Which OS are you working with? Did you create an alias for `pip` by any chance?

Comment: Try using "pip3 install ....."

Comment: @neelg no that would be explicitly using the a non-Conda `pip`. Conda doesn't use `pip2` or `pip3` aliases.

Comment: Any chance you used the `--user` flag? That would cause this.

Comment: @merv Can't we do first {conda activate env} and then use the pip3 command? I install all my packages like that!

Comment: @neelg No; try checking your `which pip3`. Should be `conda activate env` then `pip install some_pkg` (although `conda install some_pkg` should always be preferred). But as I point out in my answer, this is contra best practice recommendations. [Mixing Conda and Pip is rather precarious](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/), and doing so *ad hoc* (i.e., install-as-you-go) is error prone.

Comment: If you're using Conda, why install TensorFlow through pip?! _I wish I could use tensorflow 1.13 when virtual env is deactivated._ Why not just use multiple environment?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to troubleshoot the described conditions without more details (exact commands run, showing `PATH` before and after and post activation, etc.). Nevertheless, you can try switching to following [the most recent recommendations for mixing Conda and Pip](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env). Namely, avoid installing things *ad hoc*, which is prone to using the wrong `pip` and clobbering packages, but instead define a YAML file and always create the whole env in one go.

As a minimal example:

**my_env.yaml**

```
name: my_env
channels:
 - defaults
dependencies:
 - python
 - pip
 - pip:
   - tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0b1
```

which can be created with `conda env create -f my_env.yaml`. Typically, it is best to include everything possible in the "non-pip" section of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly that you used a wrong pip. To make sure you are using correct pip, it is usually a good practice to do

```sh
python -m pip install —user PACKAGE_NAME
```

Given that you have conda, pip should be the last resort.
Conda channel conda-forge most likely has the latest package version you are looking for.

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge PACKAGE_NAME
```

If you have to use pip, make sure you are in an environment and that environment has its own pip.

```sh
conda create -n test python=3.7 
conda activate test
python -m pip install PACKAGE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

From your described problem, I can guess that your environment is not activated in which you are trying to install the tensorflow2.0

Please make sure to activate the environment after making it.

so after creating the environment do this-

```
conda activate tf2.0
```

make sure you see this

```
(tf2.0) C:\Users\XYZ>
```

And then you install your tensorflow.